# How to automatically resize an input-box in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, textfield, pysimplegui

This is the first time I use Stackoverflow.

I am beginner, so I might doing the things in the wrong order or doing things wrong. I am learning PySimpleGUI.

#### Code

I use input-box with a "Browse" button like this:

```py
layout = [
    [sg.Input(size=(30, 1), key='-IN1-', enable_events=True), sg.Button('Browse')],
    [sg.Input(k='-IN2-'), sg.Button('-Date1-')],
    [sg.T('Starting Year:'), sg.Input(size=(5, 1), k='-YEAR-')],
    [sg.Input(k='-IN3-'), sg.Button('-Date2-')],
    [sg.B('Go'), sg.B('Exit')]
]

window = sg.Window("Chooser Using Popups", layout, keep_on_top=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    if event == 'Browse':
        filename = sg.popup_get_file('', no_window=True, keep_on_top=True)
        layout = [
            [sg.Input(size=(len(filename), 1), key='-IN1-'), sg.Button('Browse')],
            [sg.Input(size=(len(filename), 1), key='-IN1-', enable_events=True), sg.Button('Browse')],
            [window['-IN1-'].update(filename)]
        ]
```

#### Problem

When I select a path to a file too long, my input-box contains the full path but it is not fully visible.

#### Wanted

So I am looking for a way to auto-size the input-box.

I didn't find a way to auto-size the input-box.

I tried to get text length in order to set the box dimension manually but I ran into following problem:

When I create the box I don't have the path so I don't know how long it is. I failed to figure out how to change the input-box dimension after I got the path. A bit of chicken's leg story.

#### Question

How to avoid a path longer than the box?

Comment: Please format you code and solve syntax-issues first (it contained backticks and HTML-like `<kbd>` which I removed).

Answer (score -1):

An answer has been given to me and it works fine:

```
starting_value = ''
layout = [
        [sg.Input(starting_value, size=(len(starting_value), 1), key='-IN1-', enable_events=True), sg.Button('Browse')],
        [sg.Input(k='-IN2-'), sg.Button('-Date1-')],
        [sg.T('Starting Year:'), sg.Input(size=(5, 1), k='-YEAR-')],
        [sg.Input(k='-IN3-'), sg.Button('-Date2-')],
        [sg.B('Go'), sg.B('Exit')]]
```

Comment: Consult [help on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to improve your posted code. You can use [fenced code-blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by surrounding with 3 backticks.